# Printing Option<String> variable gives error after unwrapping variable

Tags: rust

If I try to unwrap a variable, and then try to print the variable, it gives the error

```
borrow of moved value: `var`
```

Full output from rustc

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `var`
   --> test.rs:6:24
    |
3   |     let var: Option<String> = Some("Hello World".to_string());
    |         --- move occurs because `var` has type `Option<String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
4   |     println!("var: {:?}", var);
5   |     println!("value: {}", var.unwrap());
    |                               -------- `var` moved due to this method call
6   |     println!("var: {:?}", var);
    |                           ^^^ value borrowed here after move
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `var`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

My code:

```
fn main() {
    // Doesn't work on String type
    let var: Option<String> = Some("Hello World".to_string());
    println!("var: {:?}", var);
    println!("value: {}", var.unwrap());
    println!("var: {:?}", var);

    // Works on i32 type
    // let var: Option<i32> = Some(5);
    // println!("var: {:?}", var);
    // println!("value: {}", var.unwrap());
    // println!("var: {:?}", var);
}
```

By the way, I am just beginning to learn rust, so I don't know that much about rust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) takes ownership of `self`:

```rust
fn unwrap(self) -> T;
```

To avoid this, you can call [`as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) first, which will give you an `Option<&T>` - a borrow:

```rust
// fn as_ref(&self) -> Option<&T>;

println!("var: {:?}", var);
println!("value: {}", var.as_ref().unwrap());
println!("var: {:?}", var);
```

`Option` has many utility methods like this, such as `as_mut`, `as_deref`, `map`, and `cloned`. I encourage you to take a look at [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) for a complete reference, they come in really handy.

Comment: Is there a reason that Option<i32> works, but not Option<String>?

Comment: because `i32` is `Copy`.

Comment: um, what does `Copy` mean? I'm only a beginner at rust, so I don't know.

Comment: See the [relevant section from the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#stack-only-data-copy) @CrazyVideoGamez

Answer (score 0):

This is because of ownership. See [the rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html) on this topic.

Basically you give the ownership of `var` from the `main()` function to the `unwrap()` function, and then you want to use `var` in main -- but `var` is not owned by `main()`.